# EV3 won't run a certain loop

Tags: ev3, software

I'm trying to make a program where an EV3 is IR controlled but if button 9 (toggle) is pressed it goes in autonomous mode. However, my EV3 will not run a certain loop in the program.

It looks like this:
[image: The big one won't run; no matter what I put in it]

The big one won't run; no matter what I put in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A program should have only one "Start" block (the green play button).
2. Your 3 segments of code are not linked together, you need to drag a "beam" from the exit of one loop to the block that should execute after the loop exits.
3. You need to link the action of pressing the button to an exit condition for your loops. You are using infinite loops. The only way to escape an infinite loop is a Loop Interrupt block. Click on the infinity symbol on the loop blocks for more options.